# Php/Webstorm - how to change from svn to git?

Tags: git, svn, webstorm

Our company version control system (VCS) standard is Subversion and I've checked out the project from svn in Webstorm.  I want to also use git so that I can easily create branches to test various approaches to the project I'm building.

When I've settled on an approach and have built some stuff out, I'll commit my changes to svn.

I've typically done this by leaving Webstorm connected to SVN and then interact with Git via command-line.

However, now, I'd like to do the reverse.  But once I'm connected to SVN for this project, how to I tell Webstorm to disconnect from SVN integration?

Thanks,
Scott

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [subgit](http://subgit.com/). This allows you to have a real git repository connected to your SVN repository. You only work with the git side and the changes are automatically synced with the SVN.